# Can I change thermal shutdown into sleep or disable altogether?

Tags: shutdown, cooling, temperature

I am having some overheating problems with my DELL XPS 13 9310 up to the point that it shuts down (not so) gracefully (with the "Windows is shutting down" screen) - point is, it doesn't crash.

**Can I change the default policy from "Shut down" to go to S1, S3 or Hibernation instead?**
Or can I disable the shutdowns altogether and instead allow the system to slow down significantly?

This is very annoying because a crash would in fact be much better, because I can just simply recover my work and browser tabs and basically anything these days. With the Windows shut down, everything closes as if I closed it and many of the things don't even save!, so it destroys all my work and everything else.

The PC doesn't seem to throttle the performance much either. HWiNFO64 does report that one or two cores did Thermal Throttle at some point, but none of them report "yes" in "Current" tab and the performance doesn't seem to degenerate at the time of shutdown either.

But what's worse, my system is not even that hot! I have only ever seen 67°C, no more!

PS: I have just cleaned the pathways, so dust is not an issue. And I ordered new paste, so I will also try to repaste the heatsink.

[image]

The last records from Event Viewer say

> **Event ID: 86**
> The system was shut down due to a critical thermal event.
> Shutdown Time = `<time>`
> ACPI Thermal Zone = Intel(R) Dynamic Tuning: TSKN
> _CRT = 331K  (58°C)

> **Event ID: 1054**
> Temperature sensor detected a failure value
> Sensor location: SKIN  ,
> Probe type: Temp
> Location: Motherboard,
> Current value: 52,
> Upper critical threshold value is: 44,
> Upper non critcal threshold value is : 42.
> Chassis location: Main System Chassis
> Previous state was: Critical (Failed)

> **Event ID: 1054**
> Temperature sensor detected a failure value
> Sensor location: DIMM A,
> Probe type: Temp
> Location: Memory Module,
> Current value: 48,
> Upper critical threshold value is: 48,
> Upper non critcal threshold value is : 45.
> Chassis location: Main System Chassis
> Previous state was: Critical (Failed)

More about my problem here https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/10-thousand-errors-quot-Temperature-sensor-detected-a-failure/td-p/8181607
PS: I resolved the freezes in the meantime (it was a faulty service), but I still get issues with overheating.

Comment: "I am having some overheating problems," - Except 54-64 °C isn't an indication of overheating.  Speedfan isn't properly configured if it believes those temperatures are "hot" or exceeding an unspecified threshold.  If your processor was overheating, it would simply "turn off" suddenly. The temperature threshold of an 11th Intel processor is closer to 90°C than 70°C.  My suggestion **remove** any and all Dell provided drivers and install the ACPI Intel drivers offered by Inte (or verify you have the current drivers by Dell).  While you are at it remove Dell software.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, I am actually considering fresh install. But if I remove all DELL stuff, are there alternatives to control e.g. battery charging levels (i.e. max 80%) and performance (cool/quiet/etc.)? Those are somewhat handy. I don't have experience with this.